# Google Big Query Get User Count by page path and Custom Dimension for Google Analytics Data

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to get number of users who visit a certain page by custom dimension. 
However my code is not matched with Google Analytics. Can anyone help me with this?

```
SELECT
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', t.date) as Date
   ,count(distinct( concat(fullVisitorID,cast(visitID as string)))) as visitor_count
   ,(if(customDimensions.index=1, customDimensions.value,null))  as orig
FROM `table` as t
   CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
   CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) AS customDimensions
WHERE
   (hit.page.pagePath ='apple'OR hit.page.pagepath= 'pear')
GROUP BY DATE,orig
```

Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't realize that I just need to count FullvistorID, it solved the problem. Hopefully this can help someone.

```
SELECT
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', t.date) as Date
   ,count(distinct(fullvisitorid)) as visitor_count
   ,(if(customDimensions.index=1, customDimensions.value,null))  as orig
FROM `table` as t
   CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
   CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) AS customDimensions
WHERE
   (hit.page.pagePath ='apple'OR hit.page.pagepath= 'pear')
GROUP BY DATE,orig
```